# difference between model-best and model-last in spacy

Tags: python, machine-learning, nlp, spacy, spacy-3

after model training, spacy has generated `model\model-best` and `model\model-last` folders. What's the difference between the two models and which one should be used for predictions?

Comment: `last` doesn't have to be the `best`. I think you should use `best`. I found in spacy doc: [Metrics, training output and weighted scores](https://spacy.io/usage/training#metrics) which explains how it uses metrics to select the best model.

Comment: I agree with you, because I found better entity predictions with the best model than last model. But if best gives better accuracy, why does spacy generate the last version as well ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`model-best` is the model that got the highest score on the dev set. It is usually the model you would want to use.

`model-last` is the model trained in the last iteration. You might want to use it if you resume training.